# Schwarz Reflection Across Circular Arc

Tags: complex-analysis

this is a basic question but I want to make sure I am understanding well (which I'm not haha).

Suppose we have an analytic function $f(z)$ on the disc of radius 2, centered at the origin.  Also, suppose there is an arc on the unit circle on which $f(z)$ is real.  Then we want to prove that $f(z)$ is constant.

Using the Cayley Transform, I know that reflecting across the real line with $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ is equivalent to $z \mapsto \frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ on the unit circle. If we call the subarc $\sigma \subset \partial \mathbb{D}$, then on $\sigma$ we have $$f(z) = \overline{f(\frac{1}{\bar{z}})}$$ in a neighborhood of $\sigma$.  Call the right half of the above equality $g(z)$.  Then $g(z)$ is analytic where defined, i.e. on the complement of $\overline{B(\frac{1}{2}, 0)}$ so by uniqueness, is equal to $f(z)$ on an annulus around $\partial \mathbb{D}$.

Here's where I'm not sure what to do.  I guess the idea is that since $f$ can be analytically extended from this annulus inward, so can $g$.  Geometrically it's obvious that this causes problems (ultimately it should have to either "flip" 0 to $\infty$ or fail the maximum modulus principle), but I can't put the proof together.  Can anyone help with the last details?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: OH, or can we make it into a bounded entire function?  Like, gluing g(z) on the outside of the unit disc to f(z) on the inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M = \text{max}_\overline{\mathbb{D}}(|f(z)|)$.  Using the notation of the question, note that on the complement of $\mathbb{D}$, $|g(z)|$ is bounded by $M$. Since $f$ and $g$ agree on an overlap (an annulus about the unit circle) they glue to an analytic $h$, which is entire since the union of the domains of $f$ and $g$ are all of $\mathbb{C}$.  But it's bounded by $M$ and thus constant, by Liouville's Theorem.