# If analytic function F is real on the part of unit circle, then F is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $F(z)$ be analytic function defined in the disk $|z|<2$. Assume
> that $F( \zeta)$ is real for $\zeta$ belonging to an arc of $|\zeta |
>  =1$. Prove that $F$ is constant.

I've encountered this problem, and my idea was using maximum modulus principle or reflection principle. But I'm not sure how to start proof.

Comment: Schwarz reflection maybe?

Comment: @spinosarus123 Could you give me a little bit more detail? I tried to use Schwarz reflection, but I'm not sure how to get the result.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1690529/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you!